# Initializing Map from an Observable view model in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, combine

I'm attempting to implment a `Map` on a SwiftUI view from a view model. Every example I find online hard codes a coordinate. In my case, I'm initializing a view model with a `Codable` struct and I have no idea what the coordinate is going to be.

I do not encounter compiler issues when I build the project, but canvas crashes. I've tried closing Xcode, cleaning derived data, etc., but that doesn't seem to resolve it.

Any suggestions re: where my mistake is are greatly appreciated.

```
class EarthquakeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var quakeData: Feature
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    
    init(quakeData: Feature) {
        self.quakeData = quakeData
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: quakeData.geometry.coordinates[0],
                                        longitude: quakeData.geometry.coordinates[1])
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1.0, longitudeDelta: 1.0)
        region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center,
                                    span: span)
    }

        public lazy var title: String = {
        quakeData.properties.title
    }()
}
```

This is my `ContentView`:

```
struct EarthquakeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EarthquakeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.title)
//            makeMapView()
            Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region)
        }
    }
}
```

// I tried this, too, but it doesn't work.

```
extension EarthquakeView {
    @ViewBuilder func makeMapView() -> some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region)
    }
}
```

### Update

This is the message from Diagnostics. Cleaning derived data with Xcode closed doesn't seem to resolve it, so I think my issue lies with one of my declarations:

```
RemoteHumanReadableError: Failed to update preview.

The preview process appears to have crashed.

Error encountered when sending 'render' message to agent.

==================================

|  RemoteHumanReadableError: The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
|  
|  BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain (3):
|  ==BSErrorCodeDescription: OperationFailed
```

### Update 2

I tweaked my data model and added a computed region var off of it, so here's how I'm getting the region now:

```
extension Feature /* Feature is a Codable struct */ {
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion {
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: geometry.coordinates[0],
                                            longitude: geometry.coordinates[1])
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1.0, longitudeDelta: 1.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center,
                                        span: span)
        
        return region
    }
}
```

At [jnpdx's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx) suggestion, I updated the region on my view model to `@Published`.

```
class EarthquakeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    `@Published private(set) var quakeData: Feature
    `@Published var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    init(quakeData: Feature) {
        self.quakeData = quakeData
        region = quakeData.region
    }
    
    public lazy var title: String = {
        quakeData.properties.title
    }()
}
```

And lastly, my View, as follows:

```
struct EarthquakeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EarthquakeViewModel
    
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    init(viewModel: EarthquakeViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        _region = State(initialValue: viewModel.region)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.title)
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
        }
    }
}
```

The new error is this. Closing Xcode, rebooting, cleaning derived data, etc. doesn't seem to resolve it, so I am quickly concluding I'm missing something basic:

> PreviewUpdateTimedOutError: Updating took more than 5 seconds Updating
> a preview from EarthquakeView_Previews in CombineQuake.app (16766)
> took more than 5 seconds.

### Update 3

Preview initialization:

```
struct EarthquakeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        let quakeData = EarthQuakeData(mag: 6.5,
                                       place: "32km W of Sola, Vanuatu",
                                       time: 1388592209000,
                                       updated: 1594407529032,
                                       tz: 660,
                                       url: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usc000lvb5",
                                       detail: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=usc000lvb5&format=geojson",
                                       felt: nil,
                                       cdi: nil,
                                       mmi: nil,
                                       alert: nil,
                                       status: "reviewed",
                                       tsunami: 1,
                                       sig: 650,
                                       net: "us",
                                       code: "c0001vb5",
                                       ids: ",pt14001000,at00myqcls,usc000lvb5,",
                                       sources: "pt,at,us",
                                       types: "cap,geoserve,impact-link,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary",
                                       nst: nil,
                                       dmin: 3.997,
                                       rms: 0.76,
                                       gap: 14.0,
                                       magType: "mww",
                                       type: "earthquake",
                                       title: "M 6.5 - 32km W of Sola, Vanuatu")
        let geometry = Geometry(type: "Point",
                                coordinates: [167.249, -13.8633, 187.0])
        let earthquake = Feature(type: "Feature",
                                 properties: quakeData,
                                 geometry: geometry,
                                 id: "usc000lvb5")
        
        let viewModel = EarthquakeViewModel(quakeData: earthquake)
        
        
        EarthquakeView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Xcode 12.4, although I'm having to make some guesses about your code since you didn't include `Feature` or the preview itself. Right off the bat, though, I notice you're using `@State` within an `ObservableObject` -- should probably be `@Published`

Comment: Thank you for looking. I updated for your suggestion. Different error, still no map :(

Comment: Still not reproducible for me (although I'm still having to infer some things about the code). Can you show how you're creating the preview? Does it work on the simulator in a non-preview situation?

Comment: Thank you for looking. I updated with the `PreviewProvider`. If I comment out the `Map` declaration, the text renders as expected.

Comment: Preview code is uncompilable because of all of the types missing from the code you've included here, but nothing looks too unusual to me. Still interested to know if this only happens in previews or on the sim/device as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run this on the simulator rather than the preview, you get a more helpful error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+167.24900000, -13.86330000 span:+1.00000000, +1.00000000>'
```

I changed:

```
let geometry = Geometry(type: "Point",
                                coordinates: [167.249, -13.8633, 187.0])
```

to

```
let geometry = Geometry(type: "Point",
                                coordinates: [45, 34, 187.0])
```

and it worked fine.

Your latitude of 167.249 is beyond the bounds of -90 to 90, which is the valid range.

Comment: LOL. USGS sends the coordinates back in reverse. I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you. https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php